# Ссылка на url в адресной строке javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Возникла необходимость вставить ссылку в адресную строку веб-браузера и перейти, то есть не просто сделать переход по ссылке из javascript, а переход в браузере. Если что знаете на эту тему напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: `location.href = 'http://google.com';`

Comment: Не совсем то, нужно не просто использовать функции javascript, а именно вставить ссылку в браузер пользователя и перейти, вы написали непосредственно переход по ссылке, а нужно само действие (вставить в адресную строку..)

Comment: А какая разница? Если ссылка окажется в адресной строке и произойдет переход по этому адресу?

Comment: "вставить в адресную строку" как и в кончоль невозможно по соображениям безопасности

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы имитировать действия пользователя нужно использовать сторонние библиотеки например puppeteer